# Uber API partner.accounts scope

Tags: uber-api

I'm Uber partner. Now I can get info from endpoints:
https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/me
https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/payments

From https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/trips and https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/vehicles I've got empty result. I think it's because partner account doesn't have vehicles and own trips.

How can I get information about my drivers such as Name, Email and Phone? Also I'm interested in detailed info about my drivers' trips.
There is a checkbox "partner.accounts" in my Uber Application Options, I've checked it, but I can't get info from this scope, there is no documents on how I can work with this scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /me endpoint to get profile information. If there is no data returned the most likely reason is the user doesn't have an approved vehicle or take trips yet.

Comment: The /me endpoint returns info about me as a Partner. I need to get info about by drivers.